# Split a string and join it back together in a different order?

Tags: c#

What is the most concise, yet readable way to split a string and put join it back together in a different order. For example, I want to split the following string:

`10-20-30-4000-50000` and I would do this via:

```
string[] tokens = original.Split('-');
```

and now I want to put it back together in this order:

`30-20-10-4000-50000`

I know I can use `Join` to put it back together in it's original form, but I don't want that.  The only thing I can think of right now is:

```
string modified = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}",tokens[2],tokens[1],tokens[0],tokens[3], tokens[4]);
```

I realized that if I do:

```
string modified = string.Format("{2}{1}{0}{3}{4}", tokens);
```

it does not keep the dashes which is what I want so is to do that, should I just do:

```
string modified = string.Format("{2}-{1}-{0}-{3}-{4}", tokens);
```

Comment: Why is Join an unacceptable mechanism?

Comment: It is not, I am just not sure how to put it back in a different order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string modified = string.Format("{2}-{1}-{0}-{3}-{4}", tokens);
```

Comment: Ah, this is at least better than my original.

Comment: Better comment that, if you use it. I took a minute to figure out how it works! Also, be sure you have 5 elements in your array!

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.Concat()`

```
string modified = String.Concat(tokens[2], "-", tokens[1], "-", 
                                tokens[0], "-", tokens[3], "-", tokens[4]);
```

Comment: Does this have a benefit over String.Format

Comment: @Xaisoft Well, it's a bit easier to read than the OP's code as the interesting logic is all off of the right of the screen.  Functionally they're close enough to identical.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `join`, you can just re-order the elements of `tokens`:

```
// swap tokens #0 and #2:
string tmp = tokens[2];
tokens[2] = tokens[0];
tokens[0] = tmp;

string modified = String.join("-", tokens);
```

Comment: I thought about this, but wanted to avoid using a temp variable.

Comment: I can do this, but seems a little lengthy `string joined = string.Join("-",tokens[2],tokens[1],tokens[0],tokens[3],tokens[4]);`

Comment: @Xaisoft: Yeah, I wasn't specifically advocating this approach. It's just that you wrote "I know I can use `Join` to put it back together in it's original form, but I don't want that", so I thought it worth making clear that you could also use `Join` to put it back together in a different form. `Format` is just as good.